# How to make #tee take in -append instead of -a option (bionicpup32-8.0)

Tags: teamviewer, overwrite, tee, puppylinux

I'm trying to run team viewer on my **bionicpup32-8.0**

Running the command `teamviewer` returns:

```
Init... 
tee: unrecognized option: append
BusyBox v1.30.1 (2019-04-24 21:49:26 +08) multi-call binary.

Usage: tee [-ai] [FILE]...

Copy stdin to each FILE, and also to stdout

    -a  Append to the given FILEs, don't overwrite  -i  Ignore interrupt signals 
    (SIGINT) Checking setup... Launching TeamViewer ... Starting network process (no daemon)
    Network process already started (or error) Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

I suppose this has something to do with the `tee` command, which running `teamviewer` will run the `-append` option whereas my `tee` takes in `-a` option.

**Is there anyway to**:

Overwrite my `tee` to take in `-append` ?

**--or--**

Overwrite `teamviewer` into running the -a option ?

**--or--**

Are there any other way of solving this ?

Comment: (1) Side note: [`tee` is specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html), `-a` is there. Your case shows there's a virtue in using portable tools in a portable way. Knowingly using `-a` is what the maintainer(?) of `teamviewer` should have done in the first place. (2) GNU `tee` uses `--append`, not `-append`, I suspect this was the option used. I can imagine that `unrecognized option: append` may refer to `--append` or `-append`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to overwrite my `tee` to take in `-append`?

This is a job for a wrapper script. Take this one:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
mark=
for arg; do
   [ -z "$mark" ] && { set --; mark=1; }
   case "$arg" in
   -append|--append )
      set -- "$@" -a
   ;;
   --ignore-interrupts )
      set -- "$@" -i
   ;;
   * )
      set -- "$@" "$arg"
   ;;
   esac
done
exec /full/path/to/real/tee "$@"
```

Replace `/full/path/to/real/tee` with the full path to the real `tee` in your OS. Check if `/bin/sh` in the shebang is the right path to `sh` (`ls /bin/sh` may be enough). Save the script as `tee` in a directory that is earlier in your `PATH` than the directory with the real `tee`. Make the script executable (`chmod +x tee`). A neat way is to create a custom directory for your wrappers; put the wrapper there and modify the `PATH` variable, so the directory is listed first.

Alternatively you can modify `PATH` for a single invocation of `teamviewer` on demand, like this:

```
PATH="/path/to/dir/with/wrapper:$PATH" teamviewer
```

One way or another, if `PATH` is right then calling `tee` will run your wrapper. Inside `teamviewer` the method will work under the following conditions:

- if `tee` is called as `tee`, not with a pathname containing `/` (in other words: if the invocation uses `PATH` to find `tee`);
- and if `teamviewer` does not overwrite `PATH` for itself.

The wrapper is rather simple. It copies all its arguments to a new array, but replaces `-append` or `--append` with `-a`. Finally it replaces itself with the real `tee`, giving it the modified array of arguments.

You claimed the troublesome option is `-append`, but GNU `tee` supports `--append`, so I suppose it may be `--append`. The wrapper detects both.

Note it's possible the tool you want to run calls `tee` with yet another non-portable option. I mean `unrecognized option` you got probably refers to the *first* unrecognized option and this *does not* mean all later options are recognized. The wrapper preemptively translates `--ignore-interrupts` to `-i` your `tee` supports. More sophisticated implementations of `tee` support options you `tee` does not support at all. If such option is used inside `teamviewer` then the current wrapper won't help. The wrapper can be easily modified so it removes some option(s), but implementing their actual functionalities is in general a non-trivial task (if possible at all). Let's hope the wrapper is enough in your case.